# PHP+MySQL Login wont work

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have been trying to get this script to go to the db and fetch data, then login etc...

My php version is 5.6. I have included the code in the both the index page [where the form is] and the problematic script in question.

---

Login form code:

```
<form class="form" action="php-process/main_login-check.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" >
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
        <button type="submit" id="login" name="login">Go</button>

        <button type="reset" id="reg-button"  
        onclick="MM_openBrWindow('app/register.php','Register @ MySite.com','scrollbars=no,width=500,height=500');javascript:RegProcess();">
        Register</button>

        </form>
```

Processing script [main_login-check.php]

```
<?php
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

/*** check if the users is already logged in ***/
if(isset( $_SESSION['id'] ))
{
$message = 'Users is already logged in';
}
/*** check that both the username, password have been submitted ***/
if(!isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
$message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}
/*** check the username is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
{
$message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
}
/*** check the password is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 4)
{
$message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
}
/*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
{
/*** if there is no match ***/
$message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}
/*** check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['password']) != true)
{
    /*** if there is no match ***/
    $message = "Password must be alpha numeric";
}
else
{
/*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database     ***/
$phpro_username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phpro_password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

/*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
$phpro_password = sha1( $phpro_password );

/*** connect to database ***/
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$mysql_username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$mysql_password = 'ThePass';

/*** database name ***/
$mysql_dbname = 'login_main';

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
    /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

    /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** prepare the select statement ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM user
                WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

    /*** bind the parameters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $phpro_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $phpro_password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();

    /*** check for a result ***/
    $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
    if($user_id == false)
    {
            $message = 'Login Failed';
    }
    /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
    else
    {
            /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_id;

            /*** tell the user we are logged in ***/
            $message = 'You are now logged in';
    }


}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
    $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later';
}
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
```

The error flagging is working OK, however and the database connection is OK. But regardless of whether I use a existing record in the database to login or not, I still get the error 'Login Failed'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: FYI your error checks for length of username and password inputs are identical

Comment: Don't use `==` to test for `FALSE` (or `TRUE` for that matter), use `===` instead, if your id comes back as `0` or `'0'`, `== FALSE` will be true!

Comment: Everything looks good giving me no chance but to doubt you store the password crypted.

Comment: proper sequence would be `execute(); check num_rows for 0 -> no match; THEN fetch the id...` what you're doing isn't "wrong", but it's also not "correct".

Comment: SOLVED - thanks for all your input, appreciate it however helpful. The problem was very simple, I was storing the password in plain text, and asking for it in SHA1, which wasn't there. I resolved it now simply by encrypting the password before it is sent to the database in the registration form. Cheers to Engin for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - thanks for all your input, appreciate it however helpful. The problem was very simple, I was storing the password in plain text, and asking for it in SHA1, which wasn't there. I resolved it now simply by encrypting the password before it is sent to the database in the registration form. Cheers to Engin for the hint! :)